# How to acquire the RSACryptoServiceProvider from the existing key container?

Tags: cryptography, .net

The Key containers of "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider" are enumerated by setting PP_ENUMCONTAINERS flag for the function CryptGetProvParam().

The enumerated key containers are set to the CspParametrs as

```
private const string _providerName = "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider"
CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters();
cspParameters.ProviderName = _providerName;
cspParameters.ProviderType = 1;
cspParameters.KeyContainerName = container;
cspParameters.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey;
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters))
                    {
                        pubKeyXml = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(false);
                    } // using
```

The CSP is not acquired for the exisiting key container . What is the reason that CSP is not acquired?